# Wordpress functions not available in class member functions

Tags: php, wordpress, oop

I am building a Wordpress plugin that has standalone PHP that is run via AJAX. As such I am using

```
define( 'SHORTINIT', true );
require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php' );
```

at the top of the PHP file so that Wordpress functions are available throughout my class and its member functions. However, the Wordpress functions are not available in the member functions.

This is a simplified version of my class but I am getting the error :

> Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wp_insert_post()

```
define( 'SHORTINIT', true );
require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php' );

class fpe_events {

    public function add_post_and_meta( $post_data ) {

        if( $post_data["ID"] ) {

            // Post exists, update it

            wp_update_post( $post_data );

        } else {

            wp_insert_post( $post_data );

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to `require_once` if your plugin is going to be in `wp-content/plugins/` See https://github.com/tommcfarlin/WordPress-Widget-Boilerplate/tree/master/widget-boilerplate

Comment: do you try to use use your file out of wordpress?

Comment: Yeah this file is outside of wordpress. it's read by ajax so it's effectively a standalone file

Answer (score 0):

You should do your PHP-Code in WordPress Plugin files.

Here is an example:

Add your JS-File to Plugin Main PHP:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'your-script', plugins_url( '/js-file.js', __FILE__ ), 
array('jquery'), '1.0', true );

wp_localize_script( 'your-script', 'your_awesome_name', array(
    'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
));
```

Ajax-Call:

```
jQuery( document ).on( 'click', '.simple-button', function() {
var post_id = jQuery(this).data('id');
jQuery.ajax({
    url : your_awesome_name.ajax_url,
    type : 'post',
    data : {
        action : 'my_php_script',
        post_id : post_id
    },
    success : function( response ) {
        alert(response)
    }
});
})
```

And run on your Plugin php file this:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_php_script' );

function my_php_script() {
  //your php script
wp_die();
}
```

Or read the codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins